# Take user input with JavaScript in the console

Tags: javascript, console, spidermonkey, gets

I need to get user input when running a `.js` in a console with spidermonkey like this:

`$ js myprogram.js`

What's the JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's `gets`?

Comment: Command line arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there is a readline() function, but it is a specific function for spidermonkey, it isn't a part of javascript.

**Example:**

1)readline-test.js:

```
print("Type some text and press <ENTER>:\t");
var userInput = readline();
print("User input: " + userInput);
```

2)js readline-test.js

For more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell.

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan could you please point to the documentation where it is said about capital L? Doc at the link I have provided state that a proper function name is 'readline()' (lower case)

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan, I've double-checked and reverted you changes to 'readline()'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really depend on the console being there. It's not something that is guaranteed, even while most browsers do have a javascript console. Beyond that I don't believe you can get values without calling a function with the console.