# Reading string data from Javascript console as with native prompt function

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-console

I have not been able to find this function in Chrome or Firefox but have seen references to it.  Given an arbitrary function `testMe(param1, param2)`, I would like to have another function:

```
function testMeConsole(){
    console.log('Enter param1:');
    var param1 = readLine();
    console.log('Enter param2:');
    var param2 = readLine();
    return testMe(param1, param2);
}
```

Again, I've seen the `readline` (or `readLine`?) function referenced but it shows as not defined for both Chrome and Firefox

Reference: [Take user input with JavaScript in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307415/take-user-input-with-javascript-in-the-console)

Comment: The question you referenced says it's in spidermonkey.

Comment: Which I thought was the JS engine for Firefox (I have version 65) but it's not a recognized function